# "avoir hâte de" + nom?

Tags: expressions, usage

L'expression *avoir hâte de* est souvent suivie d'un verbe:

> J'ai hâte de vous voir bientôt.

Peut-elle aussi suivie d'un nom ? Par exemple:

> J'ai hâte de l'été.

pour dire "I'm looking forward to the summer". Sinon, quelle est la bonne traduction pour cette phrase anglaise ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En français hexagonal *avoir hâte de* est suivi de l'infinitif :

> J'ai hâte d'être en vacances.

On n'y fait pas suivre *hâte de* d'un nom, mais on peut faire suivre *avoir hâte* d'une proposition complétive introduite par *que* :

> J'ai hâte que l'été arrive.

Non attesté par les livres de grammaire et autres lexiques, on peut trouver *avoir hâte* suivi de *à + nom*. Il me semble que c'est un Québécisme.

- > j’avais extrêmement hâte aux vacances ([blog d'un Québécois](https://mathieulaferriere.com/2-semaines-de-vacances-ne-changeront-rien-a-votre-vie/))
- > Encore plus de raisons d’avoir hâte à demain ! ([blog d'un groupe commercial Québécois](http://blogue.legroupemaurice.com/encore-plus-de-raisons-davoir-hate-a-demain/))

Et je viens de trouver confirmation de mes soupçons sur [le blog du linguiste Canadien](http://pierre-calve.blogspot.fr/2009/09/bon-ou-mauvais-francais-nos.html) Pierre Calvé :

> M. Guy Bertrand, chroniqueur linguistique à la première chaîne de Radio-Canada, disait récemment, dans une de ses fameuses "capsules" portant sur la qualité de la langue, que l'expression avoir hâte aux vacances, bien que "pas franchement condamnable", devrait être évitée parce que considérée comme régionale et qu'on devrait lui préférer des tournures telles que *J'ai hâte que les vacances arrivent* ou encore *Vivement les vacances*!

Par contre dans l'Hexagone on peut dire  *la hâte à* faire quelque chose (pas précédé de *avoir*) :

> Et ce fut un déjeuner exquis, vingt fois coupé par son zèle, par sa hâte à courir chercher du pain, de l'eau, une fourchette oubliée. (Émile Zola, [Le Docteur Pascal](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Emile_Zola_-_Le_Docteur_Pascal.djvu/193))

Donc pour répondre de façon brève à ta question, en France on dirait :

- J'ai hâte que l'été arrive.
- J'ai hâte d'être à l'été.
- Vivement l'été.

Et en plus au Québec :

- J'ai hâte à l'été.

Et comme cette tournure me plaît bien j'ai hâte à sa généralisation dans l'Hexagone.

Comment: ne dirait-on pas plutôt "être en été" au lieu de "être à l'été"?

Comment: @radouxju Je perçois un sens différent, mais être à l'été [est  fréquent de toutes façons](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=J%27ai+h%C3%A2te+d%27%C3%AAtre+%C3%A0&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&q=%22J%27ai+h%C3%A2te+d%27%C3%AAtre+%C3%A0+l%27%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22).

Comment: effectivement, à l'été est plus fréquent sur Google. Merci pour la précision.