# Préposition pour l'été + année

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, indications-de-temps

> Il a fait un voyage à Paris ____ 2012.
>
> (a) en été
>
> (b) à l'été
>
> (c) pendant/durant l'été
>
> (d) l'été

Quels choix sont possible ? Si l'expression ne contenait pas l'année, normalement on utiliserait *en été*. Mais avec l'année comme ici, ce n'est pas très clair pour moi.

Même question pour l'automne, l'hiver, et le printemps.

Les commentaires à cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25926/11550) peuvent être pertinents aussi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La question ci-dessus suscitent deux réflexions :

- « Si l'expression ne contenait pas l'année, normalement on utiliserait *en été*. »
- Si la saison est précisée par une année, quelle(s) préposition(s) peut-on utiliser et l'utilisation d'une préposition est-elle obligatoire ?

---

1. **EN été / À l'été**

Grevisse (10<sup>e</sup> édition, § 933) :

> On dit : En *été*, EN *automne*, EN *hiver* ; mais AU *printemps*. À *l'automne* est assez fréquent.
> À *l'été*, À *l'hiver* se rencontrent mais ne sont pas courants.
> On dit aussi (tour généralement employé quand le nom de la saison, à cause d'un déterminant, est précédé de l'article) : *dans l'été, dans l'automne, dans l'hiver, dans le printemps* ; on rend alors l'indication temporelle plus concrète, comme si l'on marquait qu'on est « à l'intérieur »  de la saison.

Voici ce que donne la recherche *à l'hiver, en hiver, à l'été, en été* dans Google Books :

[image: Ngram à l'hiver,en hiver,à l'été,en été]

Mes remarques :

- Si effectivement *En printemps* ne se dit pas, en note Grevisse fait remarquer que *En printemps* se dit familièrement pour « en habits de printemps ». Pour moi dans cette tournure, il ne s'agit plus d'un complément de temps, mais d'un complément de manière :

  > Le temps commence à se réchauffer et je vais m'habiller en printemps (c'est à dire avec des habits de printemps)
- Si Grevisse dit bien que *À l'été, À l'hiver* se rencontrent mais ne sont pas aussi courants que *EN été* et *En hiver*, par contre il ne fait pas mention d'une différence entre les deux expressions. Or je disais [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25926/358) en commentaire que je percevais une différence.
  J'en ai trouvé l'explication la plus complète dans cet article:  *[Les quatre saisons : à propos d'une classe d'adverbes temporels](http://www.persee.fr/docAsPDF/lfr_0023-8368_1990_num_86_1_5791.pdf)*<sup>1</sup>

Je me réfère à [l'OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3516) pour une reprise succincte de ce qu'il est dit à ce sujet dans cet article :

> Devant les noms de saison commençant par une voyelle ou par un *h* muet, on emploie souvent la préposition ***en***. C’est la préposition qui convient dans **les contextes où la saison est vue comme un espace de temps** où se déroule l’événement évoqué dans la phrase.
> Devant *printemps*, pour des raisons historiques, on emploie *au*, forme contractée de la préposition *à* et de l’article *le*.
> L’emploi de la préposition ***à*** est également possible dans des contextes différents. La préposition *à* nous fait voir **la saison comme un point sur l’axe du temps**, le moment du temps où se situe l’événement évoqué dans la phrase.<sup>2</sup>

---

2. **Si la saison est précisée par une année, quelle(s) préposition(s) peut-on utiliser et l'utilisation d'une préposition est-elle obligatoire ?**

Suite de Grevisse (10<sup>e</sup> édition, § 933) :

> *L'hiver, l'été* compléments circonstanciels de temps peuvent se passer de préposition. Avec *printemps* et *automne*, ce tour sans préposition, n'est possible que si ces noms sont accompagnés d'une épithète, ou d'un déterminatif, ou d'un complément.

Cette remarque de Grevisse revient à dire que sont tous possibles :

> Il a fait un voyage à Paris l'été (l'hiver/l'automne/le printemps) 2012.

. Mais que seuls sont possibles :

> Je voyage l'été / l'hiver.

et qu'on ne dirait pas :

> <strike>Je voyage le printemps.
>
> Je voyage l'automne.</strike>

---

Pour terminer disons que *pendant* et *durant* sont possibles avec tous les noms de saison dans le cas évoqué dans la question.

<sup>1. Revue *Langue française*, n°86, 1990. Sur les compléments circonstanciels.</sup>
<sup>2. C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>

Comment: @deLaDauversière Je ne suis pas sûre de bien comprendre ce que tu dis. Je citais une phrase de la question qui n'était pas la question mais que je pensais être une affirmation un peu rapide du demandeur.

Answer (score 3):

Tous les choix sont possibles :

- a) et c) sont les plus courants, la présence de l'année n'influe pas sur la préposition utilisable. On pourrait aussi dire « … **au cours de** l'été 2012 ».
- d) est valide aussi, une préposition n'est pas obligatoire ici, comme dans la phrase « Il a fait un voyage à Paris l'été dernier ».
- b) est beaucoup plus rare dans cette tournure, mais serait utilisé dans l'expression « ça remonte **à l'été** 2012 ». « Il a fait un voyage **à l'été** 2012 » semble plus courant en français du Canada ou littéraire. Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) souligne aussi sa rareté mais ne l'écarte pas, citant Musset: « Nous étions **à l'hiver** ». Je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un dire « Il a fait un voyage **à l'été** XXXX » et n'emploierais jamais moi-même cette préposition ici. Je pensais même que cette utilisation était incorrecte avant de découvrir des références infirmant cette impression.

« Hiver » s'utilise de la même façon que « été », donc les 4 propositions sont possibles aussi mais « printemps » et « automne » sont moins flexibles:

> Il a fait un voyage à Paris **au** printemps 2012.
>
> Il a fait un voyage à Paris **en** automne 2012.

et le plus rare:

> Il a fait un voyage à Paris **à l'**automne 2012.

Comment: d?? Non, il faut une préposition. Et j'utiliserais naturellement *à* alors que je ne suis pas Canadien.

Comment: @Gilles LBU confirme que d) est possible (c.f. réponse de Laure).